# LINQ - Convert to LAMBDA Expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

```
foreach (int i in temp)
    data.Add(i);
```

where `temp` is a `List` and `data` is an  `ObservableCollection`

Comment: why do you need to convert it to lambda? are there any particular reasons?

Comment: Just an FYI a lambda isn't like an acronym or anything. It's not even a proper noun, it's just "lambda"

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do

```
var data = new ObservableCollection(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp.ForEach(x => data.Add(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// if data is empty just pass temp in the constructor
ObservableCollection<int> data = new ObservableCollection<int>(temp);

// if data already has values you can do this using List.ForEach method
// but this would not be a LINQ since LINQ not able to modify data sources itself
temp.ForEach(i => data.Add(i));
```

Comment: any other possibilities other than this?i dont want to use foreach as it has the same behaviour of "foreach" statement

Comment: What exacly you want to achieve? I'm a bit confused by a lambda requirement, you need to pass this as delegate to some method or just make a code block shorter? If latter - just use `foreach` loop as in your question

Answer (score 0):

Not really anything wrong with what you got. ObservableCollection is a bit of a pain tho.

Here are some useful extension methods that add things like an 'AddRange' method for it.

http://zainshaikh.posterous.com/some-extension-methods-for-observablecollecti